# webpack-dev-server hot:true vs hot:only

Tags: webpack-dev-server

Upon reading [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhot), I failed to understand the difference between hot:only vs hot:true

> To enable Hot Module Replacement without page refresh as a fallback in
> case of build failures, use hot: 'only'

If we use webpack-dev-server, watch mode is enabled automatically. So in which case does the build failure happen?

I am aware of how HMR works behind the scene (HMR server, HMR runtime), but don't know what the differences between those two above.

Can someone explain? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `hot: 'only'` doesn't reload the browser page when there are errors (build fails) whereas `hot: true` will.